# if the command used does not contain a valid hex code

Tags: discord.js

```
if (command === "hex")
             {      let hex = args[0]
            

                 if(!hex) return message.reply("Please specify a hex code!") 


                 function hexToRgb(hex) {
                    if (hex.charAt(0) === '#') hex = hex.substring(1)
                    if(!hexToRgb(hex)) return message.reply("Not a valid hex.")

                    var bigint = parseInt(hex, 16);
                    var r = (bigint >> 16) & 255;
                    var g = (bigint >> 8) & 255;
                    var b = bigint & 255;
               

                    return r + "," + g + "," + b; 
                    
                 }
                
                

            
                
                let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Hex Code")
                .setColor(hex)
                .addFields(
                    {
                        name: `RGB`,
                        value: hexToRgb(hex) + ``
                    }
                )
                message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
            

            }
```

Here is my above code for the hex command. I would like the bot to send a message that it's unable to convert hex to color if the user is using an invalid hex code (e.g. #GGGGGG) or a non-hex code (e.g. "Hello"). How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex. This simple function will return whether or not it is a valid hex code

```js
String.prototype.isHex = function() {
  return ( this.match(/#?[a-f0-9]+/i)?.[0] || false )
}
```

And run it like this

```js
'#ffffff'.isHex() //'#ffffff'
'Hello'.isHex() //false
'#gggggg'.isHex() //false
```

Comment: This is also a valid answer, don't know why it was downvoted

Comment: Thank you! However, any invalid hex codes but still contains at least a valid character (which is 0-9, inclusive and A-F, inclusive) will throw an error in my terminal. Also, any string longer than 6 characters will throw an error in my terminal as well.

Comment: The same error I had prior to asking on this forum. I'll use the code to show you:

`TypeError [COLOR_CONVERT]: Unable to convert color to a number`. and `RangeError [COLOR_RANGE]: Color must be within the range 0 - 16777215 (0xFFFFFF)`

Comment: Actually, I've solved the string length by myself. My only problem is this: "However, any invalid hex codes but still contain at least a valid character (which is 0-9, inclusive and A-F, inclusive) will throw an error in my terminal."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (`#[A-Za-z0-9_]{6}`) to validate the string as a hexadecimal value preceded by a `#`

```js
function isHex(str) {
   return !!str.match(/#[A-Za-z0-9_]{6}/).length;
}

if (!isHex('some value')) return message.reply("Not a valid hex.")
```